# Why is the title of an HTML document written as a 'title' element and not as a 'meta' element?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, html-title

In a HTML document all meta information inside the `head` element is written as an attribute value of an element, e.g. the `meta` elements.

Why is the title value for the HTML document not written the same way, but placed as the content of the `title` element instead?

Comment: Probably because `<title>` is older than `<meta>`. [HTML2 spec](http://marc.merlins.org/htmlearn/html2.html#HEADING31) explicitly says "The Meta element is used within the Head element to embed document meta-information not defined by other HTML elements." and "Do _not_ use the Meta element to define information that should be associated with an existing HTML element.", giving an explicit example of title.